# find the number of xml elements under a parent element in java

Tags: java, xml, file

Im working on reading an xml file and doing some functions. What I want to know is how to get number of elements under a parent element. Say i have an xml file like following:

```
<TestCase>
    <SelectedDataTableNames name="SearchData"> </SelectedDataTableNames>

    <Open page="hsbc"  ms="5000"  />
    <Click object="hsbc.Personal_Link"  />
    <Click object="hsbc.CreditCard_tab"  />
    <Call businessComponent="Global.Verify_Search">
       <Param name="HotelName_Param" value="@SearchData_link" />
    </Call>
    <CheckElementPresent object="hsbc.Img_Hotel_logo"  Identifire="Hotel_Name_PARAM:@SearchData_ResultHotelName"  fail="true"  customErrorMessage="Searched hotel name is not present in the page."  />
</TestCase>
```

Here how to code to get the number of elements under "", which will be 6.

```
NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("Click");
            System.out.println(nList.getLength());
```

Above wont give the result as it will serch for the specified element only. Can any1 help me out with this. Any link on the topic will be also helpful. And i came across the following code which i dont understand how that works. So if the below code is correct for this question please help me in understanding that.

```
int childrenCount = doc.getChildNodes().item(0).getChildNodes().getLength();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer for the question. It works. The problem i had was ELEMENT_NODE. We have to filter ELEMENT_NODE. Here is the working code. Thanks for all those who helped be over there.

```
File fXmlFile = new File("SearchPromotions.xml");
DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = dBuilder.parse(fXmlFile);
doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

Element docEle = doc.getDocumentElement();
NodeList nl = docEle.getChildNodes();
if (nl != null && nl.getLength() > 0) {
      for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
           if (nl.item(i).getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                Element el = (Element) nl.item(i);
                System.out.println(el);
            }
      }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If your xml is always in specified format, make an xsd for it and generate jaxb classes. Then simply use jaxb read the file. Then you will be able to traverse the file with getters and simply count the number of elements you're interested with

Answer (score 1):

```
doc.getElementsByTagName("Click");
```

the code above will search for all elements with tag name "Click", in your case the result will be 2.
So if I understood your question, you wanted to have the number of immediate children of ,then you can do:

```
doc.getElementsByTagName("TestCase").item(0).getChildNodes().getLenth()
```

Comment: I tried to print it like

System.out.println(doc.getElementsByTagName("TestCase").item(0).getChildNodes().getLength());

But it says:

java.lang.NullPointerException
 at com.automatic.Main.main(Main.java:62)

Comment: that was my misktake. Now it works. BUT giving me the ans as 13 which wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Get the parent node you want by this `NodeList l = doc.getElementsByTagName("xxx"); // Could be 'TestCAse'`

If you know there is only one node with name TestCAse just do

```
Node parentNode = l.item(0);
```

By doing this you access the parent node.

Now check the number of children by doing this

```
int count = parentNode.getChildNodes().getLength();
```

Please refer the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Document.html)

**Update::**

**This happens because the DOM parser considers a space and even Enter in your xml file to be a Node so that is also counted as A node that is why you are getting so many nodes instead of just 3 or 4**

Please add this method to you program. I faced similar issue before. Clear the white spaces then do what you were doing. I am sure it will work

Pass your top most or the desired parent node to this method and then do what you were doing

```
private  void removeWhitespaceNodes(Node e) 
    {
        NodeList children = e.getChildNodes();
        for (int i = children.getLength() - 1; i >= 0; i--) 
        {
            Node child = children.item(i);
            if (child instanceof Text && ((Text) child).getData().trim().length() == 0) {
                e.removeChild(child);
            }
            else if (child instanceof Element) 
            {
                removeWhitespaceNodes(child);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: that was my misktake. Now it works. BUT giving me the ans as 13 which wrong.

Comment: the Reason behind that is there are some white spaces. Between your nodes and the parser considers those also to as A Node. Please see update.

Comment: Call my method before calculating the child nodes

Comment: Yeah found that. But thanks alot for stopping by. Your code was helpful